# PHP Desktop: SQL Server extension IMSSP error

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, mongoose-web-server

My project works fine on my wamp server, but when I moved to [PHP Desktop](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) at the same machine it stopped from working by this error:

> [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
>
> [code] => -49
>
> [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.

- PHP Version: 5.6
- PHP server:  [Mongoose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose_(web_server))
- Platform System: Windows
- Server 2012, 64 BIT

Comment: Is your wamp php version 5.6 or older than 5.6?

Comment: Did you install microdoft drivers for php for sql server v3.2 or v3.1? v3.2 supports php with version newer than 5.4, but v3.1 supports only 5.4 and 5.5. I assume you have already installed Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.

Comment: Yes I installed V3.2, and the php accepted the library, the problem may comes from the SQL Server Native Client, which installed in the windows, it is 64bit but the PHPDesktop maybe 32bit

Comment: Hi @alalp, I changed my php folder witch comes with PHPDesktop pakage, and replaced it with PHP5.4, then added sqlsrv_54.dll and worked fine

Comment: Glad to see you solved the problem. Seems that there is some incompabilities with mongoose, php 5.4< and php sql server drivers combination.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help